# AmChart multiples date values

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to create a chart with multiples date values but it's not working. I thing that the logic is good and that amChart doesn't like this date format. Any ideas ?

The working exemple :

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  type: "xy",
  dataProvider: [ {
    "ax": 16.10, <--------
    "ay": 2,
    "bx": 16.11, <--------
    "by": 2
  }, {
    "ax": 16.20, <--------
    "ay": 3,
    "bx": 16.21, <--------
    "by": 3
  }],
  graphs: [ {
    "xField": "ax",
    "yField": "ay"
  }, {
    "xField": "bx",
    "yField": "by"
  } ],
} );
```

What I'm trying to get :

```
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  type: "xy",
  dataProvider: [ {
    "ax": "2017/04/27 09:16:10", <--------
    "ay": 2,
    "bx": "2017/04/27 09:16:11", <--------
    "by": 2
  }, {
    "ax": "2017/04/27 09:16:20", <--------
    "ay": 3,
    "bx": "2017/04/27 09:16:21", <--------
    "by": 3
  }],
  graphs: [ {
    "xField": "ax",
    "yField": "ay"
  }, {
    "xField": "bx",
    "yField": "by"
  } ],
} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lktv4s4b/1/

Answer (score 1):

For date-based data, you have to specify a [`dataDateFormat`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmXYChart#dataDateFormat) for your chart object so that AmCharts knows how to correctly parse your date. Since you're using an XY chart, you also have to tell AmCharts that you have a date-based value axis (XY charts only have value axes, unlike Serial charts) and you have to specify which one is date-based. Going by your data, your X axis is date-based, so you need to at least tell it that the bottom value axis' [`type`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#type) is `"date"`:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  type: "xy",
  dataDateFormat: "YYYY/MM/DD JJ:NN:SS",
  valueAxes: [{
    position: "bottom",
    type: "date"
  }], //you can also specify the second value axis' properties if needed, but it will create a numeric y-axis for you by default if you don't
  // ... rest of your properties omitted ...
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lktv4s4b/2/

Comment: It's working perfectly, thanks a lot !
I've tried with dataDateFormat but I must have forgot the valueAxes.type !

Cheers !